# Not fitted error: Vocabulary not fitted or provided. when extracting features using TFIDF and Ngram model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to extract features from a CSV text data file, I have two columns "Label" and "text_stemmed". Some days before the project was running fine and it was showing output. But now there is an error I tried to found solution but not able to do so. I'm beginner in python anybody plz help.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import random

df= pd.read_csv('updated1.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
df.head()

df.loc[df["Label"]=='Acquittal',"Label",]=0
df.loc[df["Label"]=='Convictal',"Label",]=1

df_x=df["text_stemmed"]
df_y=df["Label"]

cv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words='english')

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)

cv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words='english')

x_traincv = cv.fit_transform(["Hi How are you How are you doing","Hi what's up","Wow that's awesome"])


cv1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english')
x_traincv=cv1.fit_transform(x_train)
cv1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words='english', ngram_range = ('1,1'))
a=x_traincv.toarray()

a
cv1.inverse_transform(a)
```

The Error:

```
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5228/2571295384.py in <module>
----> 1 cv1.inverse_transform(a)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
   1270             List of arrays of terms.
   1271         """
-> 1272         self._check_vocabulary()
   1273         # We need CSR format for fast row manipulations.
   1274         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _check_vocabulary(self)
    470             self._validate_vocabulary()
    471             if not self.fixed_vocabulary_:
--> 472                 raise NotFittedError("Vocabulary not fitted or provided")
    473 
    474         if len(self.vocabulary_) == 0:

NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-creating the TfidfVectorizer here:

```
cv1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english')
x_traincv=cv1.fit_transform(x_train)
cv1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words='english', ngram_range = ('1,1'))
```

The second version of it is written to `cv1`, and that one is never fitted, so it has no vocabulary.

What is the data you would like to train the model on?

Comment: I'm working on law case data, it in textual form.